# p cohomological dimension of a profinite group

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, galois-cohomology

I would like to know what is the $p$-cohomological dimension of $\textrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}_S/\mathbb{Q}_{cyc})$. Here $S$ is a finite set of primes containing $p$ and the Archimedean primes and $\mathbb{Q}_{cyc}$ is the cyclotomic $\mathbb{Z}_p$-extension.

I've been looking for a reference and have been unable to find it.

The $p$-cohomological dimension of $\textrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}_S/\mathbb{Q})$ is 2 and Proposition 3.3.5 (Neukirch-Schmidt-Wingberg, second edition corrected) implies that the $p$-cohomological dimension of $\textrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}_S/\mathbb{Q}_{cyc})$ is less than or equal to 2.

It also seems to follow from a result of Neukirch (see Theorem 10.5.6 NSW) that $\textrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}_S(p)/\mathbb{Q}_{cyc})$ has $p$-cohomological dimension less than equal to 1, where $\mathbb{Q}_S(p)/\mathbb{Q}$ is the maximal $p$-quotient..

But I don't know what can be said about the extension $\mathbb{Q}_S/\mathbb{Q}_S(p)$. Is this extension prime to $p$?

In fact, suppose $p$ is an odd prime and $S$ is any finite set containing the primes above $p$ and the Archimedean primes. Does there exist *any* number field $K$ such that $\textrm{Gal}(K_S/ K_{cyc})$ has $p$-cohomological dimension 1?

Comment: What is $\mathbb{Q}_S?$

Comment: The maximal unramified outside of $S$-extension?

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb{Q}_S$ is the maximal unramified outside $S$-extension..